# MediaPlayerで動画再生するとエラーが発生します

Tags: android, java, android-mediaplayer

MediaPlayerを使って動画を再生したときに以下の例外が発生します。

```
E/MediaPlayer(18065): Unable to create media player
E/DEBUG(18065): Error
E/DEBUG(18065): java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
```

以下を実行しています。

```
FileInputStream is = null;
try {
  is = new FileInputStream(mPath);
  mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(is.getFD());
} finally {
  try {
    if (is != null)
      is.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Nexus 5（Android4.4.3）で例外が発生します。特定の機種でエラーになるみたいで、他の機種では例外が発生しません。

アドバイスをよろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

自己レスです。ffmpegで音声と動画を結合した動画が再生できなかったのですが、音声のコーデック形式を mp3 から aac に変更したら再生されました。